# Will this PHP code generate a truly random password?

Tags: php, random

I wrote this code to generate a random password.

```
$s = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789";
$len = strlen($s);
$m = '';

for ($i = 0; $i < $length; $i ++) {
    $m .= $s[mt_rand(0, $len -1)];
}

return $m;
```

Is the returned password truly random?

Comment: No not truly random, you can't make something truly random in code. But random enough I guess?

Comment: it's random enough. if not to your satisfaction google `php generate random number`

Comment: your code use 62 times mt_rand, that's good enough for some purpose, but your can find "better"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any [PRNG](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudorandom_number_generator) such as the [Mersenne Twister](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mersenne_twister) (hence the "mt" in the function name) is not truly random. But it is random enough for most purposes. If you need *truly* random then you should use your operating system's randomness facilities instead.

Comment: why not? please give me an example.

Comment: @MJH: That's the nature of the Mersenne Twister. It has a maximum period, after which it will return the exact same sequence of values. It also has an internal state which, if determined, will tell you exactly which numbers will come up next.

Comment: @MJH, a "truly random" sequence of numbers lack any pattern. It's non-deterministic. How can a deterministic system like a computational system generate a non-deterministic sequence? One answer: by sampling a non-deterministic "truly-random" source of data, like radio static, gamma rays, or radioactive decay.

Comment: @MJH, but generally, you don't care. If you care, find a generator that generates "cryptographically-secure" random numbers, and that's more than enough for your use case. mt_rand should be fine for this case, though.

Answer (score 2):

Some functions are specifically built to deal with cryptography-level randomness.

[openssl_random_pseudo_bytes](http://php.net/manual/en/function.openssl-random-pseudo-bytes.php) is a good one (requires the `openssl` lib obviously). You can use it to generate password with strong randomness.

`MT` (Mersenne Twister) used by `mt_rand` is considered a `PRNG` (Pseudo Random Number Generator) whereas `openssl_random_pseudo_bytes` will attempt to use a `CSPRNG` (Crypto Secure PRNG).

This function produces bytes which you can easily [base64_decode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.base64-decode.php) to get passwords with the [base64 character set](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64).

Does all this really matter? Unless you're Facebook or a bank, probably not. `mt_rand` is probably good enough. This does serve to set you on a path to learn more about cryptography, if you're interested.

Answer (score 0):

As others have pointed out, the concept of 'truly' random doesn't exist for computers. It would actually be quite disastrous if bits were indeed random even a little.

That being said, for most random string generators you probably want something that simulates sampling from a uniform distribution so each outcome is (in theory) equally likely. Different PRNG's simulate distributions with different degrees of success with the trade-off usually coming in the form of speed.

Assuming you are comfortable with mt_rand (I don't know of any reason to not be) and the standard printable ascii character set one simple approach that produces random strings each with equally likely characters across the full printable ascii set is this:

```
function create_random_string($len) {

    $string = '';

    for ($j = 0; $j < $len; $j++) {
        $string = $string . chr(mt_rand(33,126)); 
    }

    return $string;

}
```

The meat of this is the rand(33,126) expression. It returns a decimal translatable to the printable ascii character set via chr as shown here: http://www.ascii-code.com/.

Each character is equally likely per the rand function making it as 'random' as possible with the broadest possible printable character set (again, assuming you are limiting the application to the ascii character set).